# how much has web-service been used in mule (several times)

Tags: web-services, logging, wsdl, mule

I have a web service (with WSDL) with mule to be used by people.

I want to get some information about users that use my web-service. For example : ip and time-stamp of the API invocation.

Also, I want to know how much has web-service been used in mule?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's such statistical information. However, you could add a logger processor to the flow (assuming it's a flow) marking something like "Web Service XXX was called." The logged message would also contain the timestamp, because of the logger formatter.

As to the IP that called the service, Mule places the calling address in the message Inbound property remoteAddress. So, you could just add this line to the flow:

```
<logger message="Incoming message. Caller Address: #[message.inboundProperties['remoteAddress']]"/>
```

This would log each access (which could be used for statistical purposes by an analyzing tool) and their respective calling address.

Comment: i tested ur suggestion but by ur code i can not save all requests. if i have a form in my webservice and send request by client i have not any log. only i type my web-service address into browser i have log.i want to save request from client side-service thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a good use case for either:

- A [custom interceptor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Interceptors), that takes care of storing usage statistics,
- A [wire-tap](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-WireTap) that sends to a flow in charge of storing usage statistics.